# How to make Angular CLI refer to a different node_modules folder?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am creating a new Angular project without downloading the dependencies, like: `ng new sample-app --skip-install`

I have all necessary dependencies in node_modules in a different folder of a different angular app named older-app. I want the newly created sample-app to refer to the node_modules of older-app. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why not just copy it to your new project folder?

Comment: well, few reasons. If I miss something, the app will break. If I have to update, I have to update it in both the places. Also, it is going to hog space as it will be an exact copy of the existing hundreds of dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the easiest way is to create a symbolic link in `sample-app` that points to the other `node_modules`.

If you're in windows,

```
cd sample-app
mklink /J node_modules "../older-app/node_modules"
```

Not sure about syntax in linux or MacOS, but it will be similar.

I don't really recommend this, though, because though updating or adding packages in one directory will affect both (as both `node_modules` are really the same), only the `package.json` file of the directory you are in will be modified.

This implies that, if you share the app with another person or put it in another machine, running `npm install` won't guarantee that you get the same packages, which can cause errors, so do this on your own risk.

For example, if you go to `older-app` and update Angular to version 6, `sample-app` will be modified, too. So you can change the code, developing against Angular 6. However, if you then upload that app to Github or other repository, whoever downloads it, when they run `npm install` will get Angular 5, which is sure to cause errors.

`package.json` files must always be in sync with the `node_modules` directory.

Comment: when i created the symbolic link to node_modules folder and executed ng server -o command from the new folder then webpack is still referring to old-app/node_modules/.... modules. what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

The only real option seems to be, moving the cli file.
as to see here:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3864